# CNN outputs differences when using loaded model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I am working on an image classification algorithm using the library tflearn.
I have about 20 classes and I am able to train a CNN with a specific architecture.
I am then able to predict the class of custom images with a pretty good accuracy (still in the same file)

## Train.py

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, size_image, size_image, 3])
...
model = tflearn.DNN(network)
model.fit(X, Y, validation_set=(X_test, Y_test), batch_size=400,
      n_epoch=150, run_id='model_binary', show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
images = load_images('./images/')
prediction = model.predict(images)
print(prediction)
```

When I only want to run the prediction part, I am using a second file in which I load the previously trained model.

## Predict.py

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, size_image, size_image, 3])
...
model = tflearn.DNN(network)
model.load('model.tflearn')
images = load_images('./images/')
prediction = model.predict(images)
print(prediction)
```

My problem is that Predict.py outputs are different from Train.py ones (they are actually completly wrong). I suppose this is due to the loading part but I did not manage to find how to do it properly.